# How to use variables declared inside a struct from within a struct in Rust?

Tags: rust

```
struct Parser;

impl Parser {
    const ALPHABETS_UPPERCASE: [char; 26] = [
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
    'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
  ];

  fn get_alphabet(&self) {
    self::..
  }
}
```

How to access `ALPHABETS_UPPERCASE` inside `get_alphabet` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Self::ALPHABET_UPPERCASE` (and not `self`) since this constant takes place in `Parser` as a whole and not a peculiar instance.

See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants).